# List of Comments on User Tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, users-page

I suggested this on UserVoice, but with the discontinuation of that site wanted to move the suggestion and discussion here.

A list of all comments on the User Tab would be useful. Recent comments are available from the recent tab but I'd like to have access to all comments. I would envision something very close to the list of Answers already present on the profile page.

Comment: I'd like to see this added as well... I didn't have enough points to upvote you, but you've got my support!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[This is now possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61654/ahsteele?tab=activity&sort=comments)

From the user profile click Activity, then filter by Comments.

Comment: user profile | Activity tab | **all actions tab** | comments tab

Comment: I have 5 scrollable list pages with each 20 comments. Summing to 100 comments. Where is the rest? I think that you see of each category (answers, comments) 100 entries.

Comment: I never find this on my own

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to see that too. Comments are becoming almost as important as the answers themselves.

Comment: On meta maybe...but comments aren't as important on other sites.

Comment: @jjnguy: Not as important, true, but I find it very handy to have my comment watcher tell me when there's been activity on a thread where I was active. The discussions around questions and answers on SO are often very valuable---usually not in a conversational kind of way like on meta, but often from a technical perspective.

Comment: I see your point.  It just seems to happen much less often on other sites.

Comment: I find them pretty useful on Stack Overflow. They often add a little something to an answer that the OP forgot, or offer a alternative insight (but without needing to be a separate answer).

Comment: Comment tracking would be great! A lot of comments assist the answer and it would be great to go back and review responses to your comments easily rather than trying to remember, "Damn! What was that question I was just commenting on a couple hrs ago?"

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to see that, and also to be able to see and sort by date and votes.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415462/get-all-comments-for-a-specified-user-in-a-descending-order-by-score

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer very **uplifting** to go back and see what resonated. Thanks!!

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer I get 0 rows from the query, but I have a lot of comments. I have these two userids from the urls tried: 1705829 and 1886776. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705829/timo
https://stackexchange.com/users/1886776/timo?tab=activity

Answer (score 4):

To list all stack exchange sites for you, the **current** logged in user:

- [https://stackexchange.com/users/](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity)[**current**](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity)[?tab=activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity)

To list all stack exchange sites for a **user id**:

- [https://stackexchange.com/users/](https://stackexchange.com/users/3858478?tab=activity)[**3858478**](https://stackexchange.com/users/3858478?tab=activity)[?tab=activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/3858478?tab=activity)

  ... where `3858478` is the user's id.

This will show your latest 50 actions on all sites (not just comments.)

Comment: Actually, you don't need to replace the username. In fact, you don't need the username at all. It redirects to the proper variant if you write anything after, provided it doesn't change the path. Copy-paste `https://stackexchange.com/users/3858478/tresf_posted_an_answer_on_meta_stack_exchange` for an instance - it'll redirect to `https://stackexchange.com/users/3858478/tresf`.

Comment: @tresf that's not what Zoe meant, I edited your answer to make it generic.

Comment: @shadow thanks however looking back, Zoe's comment was very clearly in regards to the username portion.  Since the `id` can add value (not logged in, another account) I'm adding both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

While we wait for this feature to be added, you can search [for your comments in the data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/how-you-can-get-a-list-of-all-the-comment-you-have-written/12714#12714).