# How you can get a list of all the comments you have written?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

How you can get a list of all the comments you have written? There is the "recent" -tab in user information but that lists only the 50 or so last events.

Comment: Feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab/31522#31522

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to do this now is to go to your activity tab and then select [the comments grouping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1431/juha-syrjala?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_comments).

This will show them, most recent first, paginated.

Answer (score 8):

Go here:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Enter this as a query:

```
select * from comments where userid = 1431
```

Comment: @shog9: Very nice, I wasn't sure if it supported that.

Comment: is there anyway to see the votes you have in a comment? is that included in the dump?

Comment: @Paolo: No.

Comment: @orique: The answer is from 2009...

Comment: You can now. The **comments** table has a **score** column containing the number of upvotes. (I suppose that's what orique's now deleted comment said?)

Comment: @PaoloBergantino this one **sorts by comment votes** -->  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415462/get-all-comments-for-a-specified-user-in-a-descending-order-by-score  Nice shot in the arm to go back and see what resonated. (Remember to use user NUMBER not name.)

Comment: The query explorer does not work, it does not fire.

Comment: @user312: Yes it does. The site is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract them from the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Answer (score 1):

The only logical way would be through the data dump. Right now there is no other mechanism in the system to go back and time and see all of your comments. Unless you wrote some kind of script that trolled through every one of your questions and answers and looked for comments you wrote.