# Finding all my comments

Tags: discussion, support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How you can get a list of all the comment you have written?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/how-you-can-get-a-list-of-all-the-comment-you-have-written)

I can find all my answers, is there a way to find all my comments? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why not is that comments were originally intended to be extremely lightweight.

The original functionality was simply to add a line of text to the bottom of a post, with your name attached.

This was before flagging, upvoting, notifications, formatting, and badges were attached to comments.

Over time, due to the community desires, the SO team has been enhancing the functionality of the comments so they are much more robust now, and that means that there may *eventually* be the ability to view [all your comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab), or even [edit comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments) but for now those are features that are lower down on the list.

Comment: I don't think editing comments will ever really come about and I don't think they are worth the time and effort to make editable.

Comment: I agree. I don't actually have any desire to see editable comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best you're going to get
[User RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/10738)

Not exactly sure why there is no way to do this, but here is some discussion on the feature request:
[List of comments in user tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab)