# Stats for Comments

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes, statistics

With the inclusion of the Pundit badge... you know this is coming to the forefront.

Will there be a stats screen for comments?  Or is there already a way to show all your comments with their votes?

Comment: You may be interested in [the Pundit progress SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/885/new-pundit-progress).

Comment: Looks like that SEDE query is no longer available. [Here is another](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66765/my-most-popular-comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [requested it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab/8460#8460) already. Come and support us! :)

Answer (score 1):

Comment stats are not required for tracking of the Reversal badge.

But with that said, the fact that there is no real good way of tracking comments other than from the recent activity page and that only shows a chronological list of comments left on things you post, I can see this being a necessity almost now.

Comment: er...right.  Don't know why I mentioned Reversal.  Up too early today.