# Comment list in user info page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

I have noticed the new Pundit badge. It's a nice badge but on user page it's not possible to find users comments.
So it would be great to have the Comment list like the Answers list.

Comment: I am almost certain that someone suggested this yesterday, but I could be wrong and it could have just been a comment on another post.

Comment: @TheTXI: was it this? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/#comment-27798

Comment: Probably. I thought I saw it on a Meta post as well, but again, I could just be imagining things (I have such a vivid imagination as it is).

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab

Answer (score 2):

You can pull this out of the data dump:

- [Count of how many comments you have at each score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104015/comment-scores-by-user?UserId=1)
- [Link to all your comment posts, sorted by score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104018/user-comments?UserId=1)

Comment: So, how would one go about finding out his/her UserID to use in the data dump queries?

Comment: @Rob: it's in the URL for your user profile (see the envelope icon, and your username, at the top of the page).

Comment: Thanks, Ether. (*$%@ 15 char minimum! :-( )