# add comments in user page (just as there are questions, answers, badges)

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, users

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow comments on user profile pages.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/allow-comments-on-user-profile-pages)
>   [List of Comments on User Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab)

add comments in user page (just as there are questions, answers, badges)

Comment: You have a new comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/allow-comments-on-user-profile-pages

Comment: I think x-x asks for something different, namely an *overview* of comments posted by the user. (*Not* for the ability to post comments on user profiles.)

Comment: Probably could do with some clarification.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586