# How do I view my past comments?

Tags: support, comments

Is this possible? That is, posts that I've commented on in the past.

Comment: (See also the more recent "How can I find comments I’ve made or posts I’ve commented on?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42654/how-can-i-find-comments-ive-made-or-posts-ive-commented-on)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of Comments on User Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the old past, not that I'm aware of (without using the data dump). However, in the recent past, your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112950?tab=activity#sort-top) has an "All Actions" tab, which shows comments, edits, questions and answers.

Comment: AllActions tab btw

Comment: All Actions tab now has a Comments sub-tab which does go All The Way Back as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jeff where is the comments sub-tab? I can only see answers, questions. But no comments. Ninja edit: it's here http://stackoverflow.com/users/651170/deathlock?tab=activity&sort=comments kinda hidden inside another sub-tab!

Answer (score 4):

Just for that, I added my "user feed" to a reader (Apple Mail, for me) that keeps history forever (rather than just the recent things as shown on the "Activity" tab). It even stores things that are deleted at some later time.

(You know, the RSS icon on the bottom of your own profile page. Or anyones profile page for that matter.)

Comment: +1, this is a better/more long-term scalable solution. (OP, this might be the one you want to accept.)