# How can I find comments I've made or posts I've commented on?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I view my past comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/how-do-i-view-my-past-comments)

I can easily find answers I;ve given, and comments made on my posts. But often I comment on an answer in a question and then never find the question again. Is this accessible anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You have the [activity tab on your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144795?tab=activity#tab-top).

Unfortunately, that's a limited list.

Other than that, you have to bookmark them yourself, or look them up in [the data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/):
[This is an example for my userid on SO](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx?qid=1021).

<sub>I would give an example with your userid, but as your accounts aren't associated, and "John" isn't particularly a unique name... ;-)</sub>

Comment: Seems a strange omission to me. I guess I can star the entire question?

Comment: @John: Yes, "starring" is one way of bookmarking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a newer way. Visit the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and create a query for showing comments from a particular user id (like in @Ether's example).

Here's mine:

```
-- Show Comments 
-- Show all my comments
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE userid=116891 ORDER BY creationdate DESC​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to wait until the next month's data dump, you can see all your comments by querying Joel C's excellent [StackQL](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/) with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE userid=<your userid> ORDER BY creationdate DESC
```