# Offline copy of my Stackoverflow Questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions

It is difficult to remember all the solutions that I got by asking question on SO. When I need any solution then I access my question online again. Many times I have no access to internet while travelling with my laptop.

I think, it may be helpful to download offline copy of all my asked question with their answers.  **Or** there may be an option for each question to download. **Or** there may be an option to print friendly format.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Ability to search my stuff?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff) and [How do I view my past comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/how-do-i-view-my-past-comments/)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are already several options to do this, some more convenient than others depending on how many questions you've asked.

1. Download the latest [site-wide data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), which you can import into a local database engine. Note that these data dumps currently occur only once/month.
2. Use the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com), which is a front-end to the latest data dump. This will let you run a query to retrieve all the questions and answers you need. Again, the data dump is once/month, and the returned format of this data may be a little bit tough to consume usefully, particularly if there are embedded images.
3. Use [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) to print a hard copy of your questions. This app uses the API instead of the data dump, so any content that is currently live on the site is accessible (i.e., you don't have to wait until the end of the month like any data-dump-based solution). Also, unlike the data dumps (currently), this app has access to all the beta Stack Exchange sites. This is probably your best option, although it has the disadvantage of the content not being updatable over time, unless you print the question again.