# How do you keep track of the comments that you leave on other questions?

Tags: support, questions, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I view my past comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/how-do-i-view-my-past-comments)

So in the current system, you get a notification of a comment to your questions, answers and a direct reply formatted like `@username` when people comment. However, I was wondering how would can we see the comments that we leave to other questions? It would be easier to keep/or find questions that I commented on and need to find again.

Comment: You can favorite a question if you expect that you'll want to be finding it again.  You can also see a lit of all of your comments on your profile if you just want to look through them all.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/users/997196/the-elite-noob?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: AWESOME, thanks mate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply go to your profile page and under "activity" select to see all your "comments".

[image]

Of course you don't have to narrow it down to comments only, but it will cut out the noise if comments is all you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now, the image cleared it up. Will accept in 10 minutes.