# Is it possible to see a list of all my comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Would like to see if I'm anyway near getting to the Pundit badge...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly, but you can do this using the data dump. Here's [the query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution) on Data Explorer for your comment score distribution, which you can run online.

Answer (score 1):

No, not currently.  It has been brought up for discussion [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab) however.  You can get all the comments using the data dump.