# How can I find my comments on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Comments on User Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab)

Sometimes I ask other users for clarifications by commenting on questions. How do I find the comments I've written on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Moshe:Both question have different tile so that I could not find it.

Comment: No problem. I suggest searching "comments". I found the original, the same way.

Comment: I am actually a bit surprised that specifically *that* question is a dupe. That other question is actually a feature request in order to be able to filter comments in the activity overview. This question has nothing of that. There's also nothing in the "Related" section on the right column.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

First click anywhere your name or profile picture appears as a link, like in top bar. It'll lead you to your profile. Make sure that you're in the *Activity* tab (this is already the default tab when you check your own profile, but not when you check other's). Then open the *all actions* secondary tab and finally click the *comments* tertiary tab. All comments which you ever posted are tracked there.

More specifically: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449897/santosh?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: This seems to do it on a per community basis. It would be very helpful if I could do a system wide search

Comment: @alpha_989 I think it will, if you do it from stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay is correct.  Try this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337220/425198

Comment: It is amazing (and I mean that positively!) that this answer is still valid after 10 years. On the other hand, it is funny (and I do not mean that positively) that this obvious feature is hidden so well in the interface that this question is necessary.

Comment: Now, on your profile page, comments are under "Responses", on the left.

Comment: Now, all comments are in "All Actions"

Comment: No way to do it across SE sites ☹️. Hold on folks let me just go through 30 of my SE accounts and figure out where I left that comment on that really helpful post I can't seem to find anymore.

Comment: @JoshHibschman it must not be that helpful

Comment: also... you can do it across SE sites.